# Sniff hostnetwork traffic from a kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have a pod running in a production cluster. The pod is for debugging purpose and I would like to sniff the host network traffic. For security reason, I cannot deploy the pod in the host network.

Is it possible to sniff the host network traffic from a non hostnetwork pod in kubernetes?

Comment: Wouldn't that be a pretty significant security bug if you could?

Answer (score 1):

A Pod only received traffic that is addressed to the Pod.

A [CNI plugin](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/#cni) is the component that you would be interested in, since that a way to plugin and intercept the traffic.